# AngularJS and Ruby on Rails 4 total count of elements in query with pagination

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, pagination

I have an AngularJS web app that sends requests to a Ruby on Rails api. The webapp has a searcher that shows results. The query is complex and has some kind of pagination (provides 20 results each time) with limit and offset, like this:

```
SELECT SELECT DISTINCT b.id
FROM ... 
WHERE ... 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

In the searcher, I would like to show the total count of results like: Showing 1 to 20 from totalCount.

To get the totalCount, my only approach is to execute the query twice, one to get the elements and another one to get the totalCount. However, I would like to avoid this because it´s a complex query.

Is there a better approach to get this totalCount?

Comment: are you using any gem for rails pagination ? or just handling paginator from angularjs ?

Comment: I´m using pagination from AngularJS with infinite-scroll.

Comment: that is not a proper way, you should handle pagination params, from server side, otherwise this goes wrong.

Comment: Rails api is just that, an API. So, it only receive requests and return results. Of course, I have a pageIndex parameter hold in the web app that is sent to the Rails API, as part as the request, so the API know which page show serve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer you to use gem 'kaminari' (https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari). Just hit an ajax call to your rails service and first count the total records and then count the matched data and send both back in json.

Comment: I didn´t know this and sounds good. I will have a deeper look. But, anyway, behind the scenes it will execute at least two queries,  right?

Comment: Probably I will investigate your approach deeper when I have a bit more time. So far, I have done like your approach manually. I mean, I execute the query two times one to get the results list and one to get the total count of elements and I send it back to the web app.